OpAmp Offset Null Pins in LTSpice
I'm simulating the following circuit, where the Op Amp is an LM741:

The LM741 is an 8-pin device, and this design calls for using 7 of them. From the datasheet, here are the pin connections:

I have an imported LTSpice model for the LM741 that is an opamp2, but that only has 5 pins - not the offset pins 1 and 5.
How/where can I get a model that will include the offset null pins?

You said you imported a model. Where did you get it from? Can you show us the netlist for it?

@SteKulov I'm using the lm741.lib file in the Psice model download here. File pastebin

Mandatory read on LM741: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Most opamp SPICE models are behavioral subcircuits and not transistor-based models.  The OFFSET NULL pins of the LM741 operate on the specific imperfections of the input transistors, so it's more difficult to model this kind of fine-tuning using only behavioral techniques.  Therefore, manufacturers will simply leave this out of the model.
Moreover, the actual input offset voltage on a real chip will vary wildly from part to part.  Therefore, the OFFSET NULL pin adjustment in real life on a real device will never match a simulation model which has the same fixed offset on every single instance of that device used in the simulator. This is because behavioral opamp subcircuits will commonly model input offset voltage with a fixed value set to the typical value (at room temperature) listed in the datasheet.  For your LM741 (page 5, Section 6.5 first entry), it's 1mV.  The model provided by TI shows this in the following section:
***********COMMON MODE EFFECT***********
*
I2 99 50 1.6MA
*^Quiescent supply current
EOS 7 1 POLY(1) 16 49 1E-3 1
*Input offset voltage.^
R8 99 49 40K
R9 49 50 40K
*

The 1E-3 on the EOS line is the 1mV from the datasheet.  If someone wanted to change the offset and see how it affects their simulation, this is where they'd do it for this specific opamp model.  This is commonly done in monte-carlo or worst-case analysis.

If you thoroughly understand why an OFFSET NULL adjustment in a simulator is mostly useless and still want to proceed anyway, then the best way around this (in my opinion) is to use a transistor-based model.  The nice thing about the LM741 datasheet is it includes a rather comprehensive schematic of the internal transistor structure (duplicated below).  The only thing missing are the fabrication parameters of the transistors.

And then a nice thing about LTspice is that it ships with an Educational example called LM741.asc which already has this all drawn out for you, including assumed transistor parameters.

Simply delete all the external components, the simulation command, and the informational note to reduce it down to this:

We want to add pins 1 and 5, so we put labels in the proper spots:

Then go to the menu-bar View->Spice Netlist to get this to pop-up:

Copy/paste it into a text editor.  This is where you change the first line (the one with the asterisk) to .subckt LM741 3 2 7 4 6 1 5 (this numbering matches opamp2 symbol).  Then also remove a few worthless lines towards the end (optional) and change the .end to .ends (required).  After all that it should look like this:
.subckt LM741 3 2 7 4 6 1 5
Q1 N001 3 N007 0 NP
Q2 N001 2 N008 0 NP
Q5 N010 N009 N008 0 PN
Q6 N012 N009 N007 0 PN
Q7 N012 N015 1 0 NP
Q8 N010 N015 5 0 NP
Q3 7 N012 N015 0 NP
Q4 N001 N001 7 0 PN
R1 1 4 1K
R2 N015 4 50K
R3 5 4 1K
Q9 N009 N001 7 0 PN
Q10 N002 N002 7 0 PN
Q11 N003 N002 7 0 PN
Q12 N013 N013 4 0 NP
Q13 N009 N013 N017 0 NP
R4 N017 4 5K
Q14 N003 N004 N006 0 NP
Q15 N006 N014 N016 0 NP
Q16 N006 N010 N014 0 NP
R5 N014 4 50K
R6 N016 4 50
Q17 N010 N016 4 0 NP
C1 N003 N010 30p
R7 N006 N004 7.5K
R8 N003 N004 4.5K
Q18 7 N003 N005 0 NP
Q19 4 N006 N011 0 PN
R9 N005 6 25
R10 6 N011 50
Q20 N003 N005 6 0 NP
R13 N002 N013 39K
.model NP NPN(BF=125 Cje=.5p Cjc=.5p Rb=500)
.model PN LPNP(BF=25 Cje=.3p Cjc=1.5p Rb=250)
.ends

You can save this text file as LM741.lib or whatever you feel like calling it.  When you close the modified education example, it will ask you if you want to save it.  Probably a good idea to NOT save it.  Anyway, if you're satisfied with this level of work, you can now follow the procedure in this article to auto-generate a symbol for this subcircuit and use it.
If you want to make a more detailed symbol, let's try doing that now.  You mentioned you used opamp2 before, so that's a good place to start.  Open/create a schematic and put an opamp2 on the schematic.  Right-click the instance and click Open Symbol:.

Now you edit the symbol to include the two OFFSET NULL pins. I'm not going to go into every detail here.  The gist of what I did is that I moved the negative supply pin over to the left, added two pins next to it with netlist orders 6 and 7 (important!), added two "NL" text labels, changed the "opamp2" text to "opamp3", and then "saved-as" this symbol out as opamp3.asy.

We can now use this symbol in your schematic similar to how you previously used opamp2.  The pin ordering for the .subckt line we made earlier should match this new symbol.


Amazing answer, thank you so much!
